# Julia: How to execute some code on exit of a function? E.g. lik R's `on.exit`?

Tags: julia

I have a piece of code that I run and I want to execute some code on the exit of a function, e.g. to close a connection.

```
fn(io) = begin
  write(io)
  # do lots of stuff which can fail
  ...
  # want close connection
  on_exit(()->close(io))
end
```

Answer (score 7):

For this particular example you would probably use a `do` block:

```
open("myfile.txt", "w") do io
    write(io, "Hello world!")
end
```

In the more general case you can use `finally`. From the docstring:

> Run some code when a given block of code exits, regardless of how
>   it exits. For
>       example, here is how we can guarantee that an opened file is closed:
>
> ```
>   f = open("file")
>   try
>       operate_on_file(f)
>   finally
>       close(f)
>   end
> ```

Comment: While this seems to be what @xiaodai is looking for, it's not literally the answer to the question. @Lyndon's `atexit` answer (now deleted) is the more direct answer to this question.

Comment: Isn't it rather that `on.exit` may not have been a relevant example?

Comment: In that case the question should be reworded of xiaodai agrees.